# CSV ヘッダーの追加と列名の順番変更について

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Pythonで既存のcsvにヘッダーの追加と列名の順番変更を行いたいです。
データ毎回不定期に変わります。下記の①〜③条件で変わります。

```
①既存のCSV　順番の変更
A       B      C    D    　E　  F        
test1 test2 test3 test5 test4 test6

②既存のCSV　D,Fの列がない時　　　　　　
A       B      C    E            
test1 test2 test3 test4 

③既存のCSV E列がない時と順番が違う時
A       B     C      F      D  
test1 test2 test3 test6 　test5
```

こちらコードを作成しましたがヘッダーを追加すると既存の列のデータが消えてしまいます。
※ないときだけヘッダーを追加します。
ヘッダー を追加する際に列のデータが消えないようにどうしたらよろしいでしょうか。
また、最初の列に”0”が付きます。”0”が付かないようにどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか。

```
import pandas as pd # pandasをpdとしてインポート
 
# データをdfに読み込み。
df = pd.read_csv("\\Users\\Desktop\\test.csv")

# 列の追加
df = df[['A','B','C','D','E','F']]

# 順番を変更
df['D'] = ''
df['E'] = ''
df['F'] = ''
print(df)

df.to_csv("\\Users\\Desktop\\test1.csv")
#print(df)
```

現在の実行結果

```
      A     B      C D E F
0  test  tes2  test3
```

どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。
お手数ですが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 他の人が調査・検証出来るように、元々のCSVファイルのデータについても [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) を参考に問題を再現できる最小限のデータをテキストで提示してみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

下記dfをサンプルとします。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(18).reshape(-1,6))
print(df)
#   0   1   2   3   4   5
#0  -0.021010   0.081681    0.328082    0.616223    0.036896    -0.452351
#1  0.523241    -0.925194   -0.332328   0.973592    0.541788    -0.861261
#2  -0.848678   -0.572776   0.420053    -1.872105   -0.819465   -1.303716
```

> ヘッダー を追加する際に列のデータが消えないようにどうしたらよろしいでしょうか。

ヘッダーの追加は下記のようなコードとなります。

```
df.columns = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
print(df)
#   A   B   C   D   E   F
#0  -0.021010   0.081681    0.328082    0.616223    0.036896    -0.452351
#1  0.523241    -0.925194   -0.332328   0.973592    0.541788    -0.861261
#2  -0.848678   -0.572776   0.420053    -1.872105   -0.819465   -1.303716
```

> 列名の順番変更を行いたいです。

列名の順番変更は下記のようなコードとなります。

```
df = df.reindex(columns=['B','C','A','D','F','E'])
print(df)
#   B   C   A   D   F   E
#0  0.081681    0.328082    -0.021010   0.616223    -0.452351   0.036896
#1  -0.925194   -0.332328   0.523241    0.973592    -0.861261   0.541788
#2  -0.572776   0.420053    -0.848678   -1.872105   -1.303716   -0.819465
```

> また、最初の列に”0”が付きます。

indexと呼ばれるものです。不要であればCSV出力する際に下記のようなコードにしましょう。

```
df.to_csv("\\Users\\Desktop\\test1.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。できました。